# Interfaces vs Generics?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have some work code whereby using generics has started to make the code look more confusing than it should.

Is it possible that I do away with generics and use interfaces for member types, constructor types, method parameter types and method return types?

What would generic provide, that the above using interfaces would not? I understand generics does compile-time checking when retrieving elements (to stop wrong casting- like in the old days), but wouldnt the compiler detect if I tried inserting types which were not a sub type of the interface required?

Comment: Could you post a code example to give us an idea on what you are doing?

Comment: You question sounds rather confusing. Commonly you use generics and interfaces in totally different scenarios.

Comment: @Keppil- the code is too large. I dont really use many collections. I was going to use generics for a composite object which contains a member object. The only use for generics would be when retrieving the member object?

Comment: So what will generics provide that using my Interfaces approach will not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generics makes the **Collections more type safe**.

If there is an extensive use of Collections in your working code, i will prefer sticking with
the generics.

And moreover as the infamous proverb states, "program in Interface, not in implementation", **Interface is moreover for flexibility than type safety.**

Generics are **also used for** Class, method , interfaces, variables, constructor. etc....

See these link for more details :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html

Comment: Collections were and continue to be a major use case of generics. That does not mean they were the sole reason generics were added to Java.

Comment: It can also be used for Class, method , interfaces, variables, constructor. etc....

Comment: @Ben pls see this paragraph `The Need for Generics

The motivation for adding generics to the Java programming language stems from the lack of information about a collection's element type, the need for developers to keep track of what type of elements collections contain, and the need for casts all over the place. ` at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html

Comment: So does using interfaces not fully provide what generics can do? I have no need to cast anything with my interface approach.

Comment: I said if you have lots of collections involved in your code its better to go with generics. I prefer interfaces at places where i need objects to play different roles.

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra what about not a collection, but a composite relationship and thinking of using the generics for the member types?

Comment: Ya offcourse you can do it, composite + generic members... i mentioned above where else other than collections, generics can be use.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces announce to all how a class must behave at all times. On the other hand type parameters (generics) let a client decide how the class should behave in a particular instance.

Type parameters make a class generic by allowing it to process a range of object types with just the one set of methods and fields, and provide compile-time checking to make sure that only the specified type is being used by each particular instance.

If you try to offer such flexibility using interfaces, you will have to write multiple versions of the same methods and classes, where each version does basically the same thing but with a different explicit type. This will be boring (which leads to cut-and-paste errors) and bulky, without adding anything at all.

The generic syntax is a bit funky looking, but you quickly get used to it, so don't let the initial ugliness of the angle brackets stop you taking advantage of a powerful feature.